# calling authentication middleware through app.use()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am little new to node js and so my all concepts regarding app.js configuration is not clear. Hence seeking some help from the community.

Currently I have following code as middleware for authentication in app.js file.

```
          var authChecker = function(req, res, next){
        if(req.query && (req.query.userName || req.query.username)){ // if api query is dependent on the user, validate its token.
          try{
            var authToken;
            req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] == "Bearer" ? authToken = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1] : "";
            var user = jwt.verify(authToken, 'secretkey');
            if(req.query.userName == user.username){
              next();
            }
            else{
              res.cookie('username', '', {expires: new Date(0)});
              res.cookie('token', '', {expires: new Date(0)});
              return res.status(401).json({"msg": "Authentication required."});
            }
          }
          catch(err){ // if not able to validate the token, then expire all the available token
            res.cookie('username', '', {expires: new Date(0)});
            res.cookie('token', '', {expires: new Date(0)});
            return res.status(401).json({"msg": "Authentication required."})
          }
        }
        else{
          next();
        }
      };
```

And I use this in same app.js file for authenticating some of the APIs.

```
          app.namespace('/api', function () {
          app.get('/abc', authChecker, abc.cde);

          app.get('/cde', efg.ghi); //authentication not required for this API.
```

Now I want to modularize this. 
Instead of defining authChecker in app.js, I want to have it define in a different file, and use it similarly. 
Can anyone please help me here.
I think we can achieve this somehow by using app.js, but not sure exactly how.
Please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create `auth.js` file, put your code then export `authChecker` function like this

```
var authChecker = function(req, res, next){
  if(req.query && (req.query.userName || req.query.username)){ // if api query is dependent on the user, validate its token.
    try{
      var authToken;
      req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] == "Bearer" ? authToken = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1] : "";
      var user = jwt.verify(authToken, 'secretkey');
      if(req.query.userName == user.username){
         next();
      } else {
         res.cookie('username', '', {expires: new Date(0)});
         res.cookie('token', '', {expires: new Date(0)});
         return res.status(401).json({"msg": "Authentication required."});
       }
     } catch(err) { // if not able to validate the token, then expire all the available token
       res.cookie('username', '', {expires: new Date(0)});
       res.cookie('token', '', {expires: new Date(0)});
       return res.status(401).json({"msg": "Authentication required."})
     }
   } else {
     next();
   }
};

module.exports = {
  authChecker: authChecker,
}
```

in `app.js` import like this

```
var auth = require('./auth.js'); // path to auth.js file
app.get('/abc', auth.authChecker, abc.cde);
```

learn more about nodejs module here: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answer. All answer seems right but since this answer is more detailed and answered first, I am accepting this.

Answer (score 1):

Create new file:

> authChecker.js

```
var authChecker = function(req,res,next) {
//your code goes here
}
export default authChecker; // you have to write this line
```

So in any other js files you can require this:

```
var authChecker = require("./pathToAuthChecker");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the authChecker in a separate file and export it for use in app.js

**auth.js**

```
module.exports = {
  authChecker: function(req, res, next){..logic..}
}
```

**app.js**

```
auth = require("auth") //path to auth.js
app.get("/abc", auth.authChecker, function(req, res){});
app.get("/cde", function(req, res){});
```

Assuming your project layout is:

```
/root
  |-app.js
  |-auth.js
```